# Implement an API for probability distributions

Tags: code-golf, probability-theory

## Introduction

In this challenge, your task is to implement a collection of simple functions that together form a usable mini-library for simple probability distributions.
To accommodate some of the more esoteric languages people like to use here, the following implementations are acceptable:

1. A code snippet defining a collection of named functions (or closest equivalents).
2. A collection of expressions that evaluate to named or anonymous functions (or closest equivalents).
3. A single expression that evaluates to several named or anonymous functions (or closest equivalents).
4. A collection of independent programs that take inputs from command line, STDIN or closest equivalent, and output to STDOUT or closest equivalent.

## The functions

You shall implement the following functions, using shorter names if desired.

1. `uniform` takes as input two floating point numbers `a` and `b`, and returns the uniform distribution on `[a,b]`. You can assume that `a < b`; the case `a ≥ b` is undefined.
2. `blend` takes as inputs three probability distributions `P`, `Q` and `R`. It returns a probability distribution `S`, which draws values `x`, `y` and `z` from `P`, `Q` and `R`, respectively, and yields `y` if `x ≥ 0`, and `z` if `x < 0`.
3. `over` takes as input a floating point number `f` and a probability distribution `P`, and returns the probability that `x ≥ f` holds for a random number `x` drawn from `P`.

For reference, `over` can be defined as follows (in pseudocode):

```
over(f, uniform(a, b)):
    if f <= a: return 1.0
    else if f >= b: return 0.0
    else: return (b - f)/(b - a)

over(f, blend(P, Q, R)):
    p = over(0.0, P)
    return p*over(f, Q) + (1-p)*over(f, R)
```

You can assume that all probability distributions given to `over` are constructed using `uniform` and `blend`, and that the only thing a user is going to do with a probability distribution is to feed it to `blend` or `over`.
You can use any convenient datatype to represent the distributions: lists of numbers, strings, custom objects, etc.
The only important thing is that the API works correctly.
Also, your implementation *must* be deterministic, in the sense of always returning the same output for the same inputs.

### Test cases

Your output values should be correct to at least two digits after the decimal point on these test cases.

```
over(4.356, uniform(-4.873, 2.441)) -> 0.0
over(2.226, uniform(-1.922, 2.664)) -> 0.09550806803314438
over(-4.353, uniform(-7.929, -0.823)) -> 0.49676329862088375
over(-2.491, uniform(-0.340, 6.453)) -> 1.0
over(0.738, blend(uniform(-5.233, 3.384), uniform(2.767, 8.329), uniform(-2.769, 6.497))) -> 0.7701533851999125
over(-3.577, blend(uniform(-3.159, 0.070), blend(blend(uniform(-4.996, 4.851), uniform(-7.516, 1.455), uniform(-0.931, 7.292)), blend(uniform(-5.437, -0.738), uniform(-8.272, -2.316), uniform(-3.225, 1.201)), uniform(3.097, 6.792)), uniform(-8.215, 0.817))) -> 0.4976245638164541
over(3.243, blend(blend(uniform(-4.909, 2.003), uniform(-4.158, 4.622), blend(uniform(0.572, 5.874), uniform(-0.573, 4.716), blend(uniform(-5.279, 3.702), uniform(-6.564, 1.373), uniform(-6.585, 2.802)))), uniform(-3.148, 2.015), blend(uniform(-6.235, -5.629), uniform(-4.647, -1.056), uniform(-0.384, 2.050)))) -> 0.0
over(-3.020, blend(blend(uniform(-0.080, 6.148), blend(uniform(1.691, 6.439), uniform(-7.086, 2.158), uniform(3.423, 6.773)), uniform(-1.780, 2.381)), blend(uniform(-1.754, 1.943), uniform(-0.046, 6.327), blend(uniform(-6.667, 2.543), uniform(0.656, 7.903), blend(uniform(-8.673, 3.639), uniform(-7.606, 1.435), uniform(-5.138, -2.409)))), uniform(-8.008, -0.317))) -> 0.4487803553043079
```

Comment: Can we use built-in functions to make them?

Comment: @AndréMuta I forgot that Mathematica probably has built-ins for all of this... but I'm going to allow them, as long as they follow the rules.

Comment: What is your suggestion on how to represent floating point data in BrainFuck?

Comment: @flawr For languages that don't have native floating point numbers, you can use any convenient encoding for floats between -10.0 and 10.0 (exclusive) that has at most 0.001 difference between consecutive values. The output should be accurate to within 0.01 difference for the test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CJam, 58 bytes

```
{[\]}:U;
{[@]}:B;
{_,2={~1$-@@-\/0e>1e<}{6Yb@f*\.{O})[_1@-].*:+}?}:O;
```

These are postfix operators that work on the stack: `2.0 1.0 3.0 U O` is `over(2, uniform(1, 3))`.

#### Score count

`{[\]}` is the function itself, `:U;` assigns it to the name `U` and pops it. Essentially this isn't part of the function, so by score counting rule 2, I'd only have to count `{[\]}`. `B` is defined similarly.

However, `O` is recursive, and if I don't specify a name, there's no way to recurse. So here, I'd be inclined to count the `:O;` part. Then my score is `5+5+48=58` bytes in total.

#### Explanation

`U` pops two arguments and makes a pair in reverse order: `a b  =>  [b a]`.

`B` pops three arguments and makes a triple in rotated order: `a b c  =>  [b c a]`.

`O`'s structure is as follows:

```
{             }:O;   Define O as this function:
 _,2=        ?       If the argument list's length is 2:
     {~Γ}            Append the list to the stack and execute subprogram Γ.
         {~Δ}        Else, do the same, but execute subprogram Δ.
```

Subprogram *Γ* handles uniform distributions:

```
Executed ops      Explanation   Stack contents
============      ===========   ==============
                  Initial       f; b; a
1$                Copy b        f; b; a; b
  -               Difference    f; b; (a-b)
   @@             Rotate x2     (a-b); f, b
     -            Difference    (a-b); (f-b)
      \/          Flip divide   (f-b)/(a-b)
        0e>       Clamp low     max(0, (f-b)/(a-b))
           1e<    Clamp high    min(1, max(0, (f-b)/(a-b)))
```

Subprogram *Δ* handles blended distributions:

```
Executed ops              Explanation    Stack contents
============              ===========    ==============
                          Initial        f; [Q R P]
6Yb                       Push [1,1,0]   f; [Q R P]; [1 1 0]
   @                      Rotate         [Q R P]; [1 1 0]; f
    f*                    Multiply each  [Q R P]; [f f 0]
      \                   Swap           [f f 0]; [Q R P]
       .{O}               Pairwise O     [q r p]
           )              Uncons         [q r] p
            [_1@-]        [p, 1-p]       [q r] [p 1-p]
                  .*:+    Dot product    q*p+r*(1-p)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 103

```
u=b=->*a{a}
o=->f,d{d[2]?(p=o[0,d[0]])*o[f,d[1]]+(1-p)*o[f,d[2]]:(f<a=d[0])?1:(f>b=d[1])?0:(b-f)/(b-a)}
```

Defines three lambdas, `u`, `b`, and `o`. `u` and `b` just create two-element and three-element arrays respectively. `o` assumes a two-element array is a uniform distribution and a three-element one is a blend of three distributions. In the latter case it calls itself recursively.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 73

Time for a little "functional programming" in MATLAB. These are 3 anonymous functions. Uniform and blend are called the same way as the examples, but for `over` the arguments should be swapped. I don't really need an `over` since the first two return functions, but as a formality `feval` is a function that can call a function.

```
%uniform
@(a,b)@(x)(x<b)*min(1,(b-x)/(b-a))
%blend
@(P,Q,R)@(x)P(0)*(Q(x)-R(x))+R(x)
%over
@feval
```

Now MATLAB's parsing and evaluation system is a little wonky to say the least. It doesn't allow you to directly call a function that was returned from a function. Instead, one must first save the result to a variable. The 4th example could be done as follows:

```
x=uniform(-5.233,3.384);y=uniform(2.767,8.329);z=uniform(-2.769,6.497);over(blend(x,y,z),0.738)
```

However, it is possible to get around this by using `feval` to call all the functions. If the following definitions are used, then the examples can be evaluated exactly as they are written.

```
uniform=@(a,b)@(x)(x<b)*min(1,(b-x)/(b-a))
blend=@(P,Q,R)@(x)feval(P,0)*(feval(Q,x)-feval(R,x))+feval(R,x)
over=@(x,f)feval(f,x)
```

Comment: Functions making functions... [how perverse!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xr9s6-tuppI)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>129</s> 116 bytes

```
u=UniformDistribution@{##}&;b=If[x<0,z,y]~TransformedDistribution~{x\uF3D2#,y\uF3D2#2,z\uF3D2#3}&;o=Probability[x>=#,x\uF3D2#2]&
```

`u`, `b` and `o` are `uniform`, `blend`, and `over` respectively.Wrapper over the standard functions. Replace the `\uF3D2`s with the 3-byte character. Just returns `0` and `1` for cases 1, 4, and 7.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 146 bytes

```python
u=lambda*a:a
b=u
x=lambda f,a,b:[int(f<=a),(b-f)/(b-a)][a<f<b]
y=lambda f,p,q,r:o(0,p)*o(f,q)+(1-o(0,p))*o(f,r)
o=lambda f,p:[x,y][len(p)-2](f,*p)
```

Same strategy as histocrat's Ruby answer, but in Python. To do recursion without a Z-combinator (which would be costly), `x` and `y` are defined as helper functions that evaluate `over` for 2- and 3-length argument tuples (`uniform` and `blend` arguments, respectively).

[Test cases on ideone](http://ideone.com/C0zWX6)

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 104 bytes

I hope this is still valid, as this only works for distributions with support in [-10,10] which is the requirement for languages that have no floating point support. The support vector and the accuracy can be easily adjusted by just altering corresponding numbers. `u,o,b` is for `uniform,blend,over`. The pdf is just represented as a discrete vector. I think this approach can easily be transferred to other languages.

```
D=1e-4;X=-10:D:10;
u=@(a,b)(1/(b-a))*(a<X&X<b);
o=@(x,d)sum(d.*(X>x))*D;
b=@(p,q,r)o(0,p).*q+(1-o(0,p)).*r;
```

You can test them if you define those functions first and then just paste this code:

```
[o(4.356, u(-4.873, 2.441)) , 0.0;
o(2.226, u(-1.922, 2.664)) , 0.09550806803314438;
o(-4.353, u(-7.929, -0.823)) , 0.49676329862088375;
o(-2.491, u(-0.340, 6.453)) , 1.0;
o(0.738, b(u(-5.233, 3.384), u(2.767, 8.329), u(-2.769, 6.497))) , 0.7701533851999125;
o(-3.577, b(u(-3.159, 0.070), b(b(u(-4.996, 4.851), u(-7.516, 1.455), u(-0.931, 7.292)), b(u(-5.437, -0.738), u(-8.272, -2.316), u(-3.225, 1.201)), u(3.097, 6.792)), u(-8.215, 0.817))) , 0.4976245638164541;
o(3.243, b(b(u(-4.909, 2.003), u(-4.158, 4.622), b(u(0.572, 5.874), u(-0.573, 4.716), b(u(-5.279, 3.702), u(-6.564, 1.373), u(-6.585, 2.802)))), u(-3.148, 2.015), b(u(-6.235, -5.629), u(-4.647, -1.056), u(-0.384, 2.050)))) , 0.0;
o(-3.020, b(b(u(-0.080, 6.148), b(u(1.691, 6.439), u(-7.086, 2.158), u(3.423, 6.773)), u(-1.780, 2.381)), b(u(-1.754, 1.943), u(-0.046, 6.327), b(u(-6.667, 2.543), u(0.656, 7.903), b(u(-8.673, 3.639), u(-7.606, 1.435), u(-5.138, -2.409)))), u(-8.008, -0.317))) , 0.4487803553043079]
```

Comment: Matlab has FP support, so I think that this would be invalid.

Comment: I'm hesitant to allow this, since Matlab supports floating point numbers natively. If you can replace `X` and `D` with `MIN_FLOAT` and `MAX_FLOAT` (or whatever Matlab calls them), then this is a valid approach.

Comment: Yes, you could ouse `realmax`/`realmin`, you could even make a vector that goes throu all floating point number if you have enough memory.